# What is a efficient algorithm to compute e(u, v) in bilinear map

Tags: group-theory, pairings, oblivious-transfer

My problem is about this paper ***Efficient k-out-of-n oblivious transfer scheme with the ideal communication cost*** https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397517309143

I don't know what is the "efficient algorithm" in section 3, paragraph 2, the second sentence of this paper.

Could you give me some explanation or related knowledge about this?

Answer (score 1):

These schemes are usually instantiated with an elliptic curve pairing (Weil, Tate, Ate, Eta...) essentially based on [Miller's algorithm](https://crypto.stanford.edu/miller/) on a pairing-friendly elliptic curve. Miller's algorithm uses polynomially many field operation to produce the output and hence is considered efficient. Further optimisations are possible.